# File opening error while running Rscript as cronjob

Tags: r, cron, anaconda, package-managers

I am trying to run an R script as a cronjob with a conda environment. Running the script from terminal works well with following `script.sh`

```
/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/{env-name}/bin/Rscript '/ABSOLUTE_PATH/script.R'  >> '/ABSOLUTE_PATH/script.log' 2>&1
```

However, when defining the job in `crontab -e` as

```
30 14 * * * /ABSOLUTE_PATH/script.sh
```

Results in

`Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/admenv/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Execution halted`

I have tried to run it as

`/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/{env-name}/bin/R '/ABSOLUTE_PATH/script.R'  >> '/ABSOLUTE_PATH/script.log' 2>&1`

`source /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/activate {env-name}; Rscript '/ABSOLUTE_PATH/script.R'  >> '/ABSOLUTE_PATH/script.log' 2>&1`

which all resulted in the same error as a cronjob.
Reinstalling packages in conda `conda remove r-tidyverse; conda install -c r r-tidyverse` did not help.

Used R version is 3.6.2 and Anaconda 4.8.2. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely using the environment wrongly. Conda cannot be directly called in a bash script, as per it wants to use `conda init bash` to be used in shell.

I managed to make this work with following steps:

```
# Create the enviroment to be used
conda create -n r-env r-base r-essentials <other packages, for example r-tidyverse r-dbi>
```

Next create the `script.sh`:

```
conda activate r-env
Rscript <ABSOLUTE_PATH>/script.R
```

Then call the cronjob as an interactive (the `-i` option) shell which allows conda environment to be activated.

```
# You can use obliviously any time you like
* * * * * bash -i <ABSOLUTE_PATH>/script.sh <any error streams>
```

Tested with R script

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(ggplot2)
print("Hello world!")
```

which was piped to external file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks vahvero for the excellent reply. The problem seemed to be in my conda environment, so just recreating the environment with your instructions solved the problem!